# Why Are Images Showing Larger than they Should?

Tags: css, wordpress, image

Three images on [this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/460/the-post-it-productivity-method/) are showing up larger than the CSS specifies. I'm using Chrome 10, and the images are "Subscribe via RSS" "Follow us on Twitter" (both should be 170px but are showing as 200px) {[[RESOLVED]] and "Women who read this also read" should be 780px as the original pic is but is showing at 936px}.

Comment: lookking perfect in my chrome :)

Comment: Which browser are you finding these inconsistencies. I just had a quick look in Chrome and it all looks OK. Also FYI, the paragraphs above the 'Women who read this also read' image are only 650px wide.

Comment: @marcel Thanks for the tip on reseting the browser's zoom. I did this but the images are still showing up too big in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @marcel, Ahh! Ok, I'll re-do that image to 650px - I must have read it wrong. But what about the two other images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (zero) to reset your browser's zoom. The "Women who read this also read" image is `936px` wide if zoomed in one level in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS applied to those images. To avoid issues like this happening, try adding width/height attributes to the img tag itself

Comment: Is there an instruction to make an image show at it's original height/width? Thanks @tristar

Comment: <img width="170px" height="30px" src="yourimage.jpg" />

You could automate it with PHP, but it depends how you're adding the images.The "Women who read this also read" part in my FF is too big, and I'm not zoomed in.